# How does kernel support swap limit?

Tags: kernel, container

When i run docker info command on my ubuntu 13.04 with kernel 3.8.0-19-generic

i got a warning

```
no swap limit support
```

How can i solve this?

**docker info**

```
Containers: 10
Images: 37    
Driver: aufs    
Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
Dirs: 59

WARNING: No swap limit support
```

Answer (score 22):

[You need a couple of arguments to be passed to the Kernel at boot](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.sysutils.docker.user/31).

Run `sudoedit /etc/default/grub` in a terminal and edit the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` line so it looks like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1"
```

Save and exit and then run `sudo update-grub` and reboot. That should be enough.

Comment: I run this command sudoedit/etc/default/grub and edit the grub file by

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1" after that update-grub and

reboot.But now also i got the same warning

Comment: Check your dmesg output, particularly the kernel command line that the arguments were passed to the kernel by grub.  I had to edit GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT instead.

Comment: how could I check this config is worked or not?